# Simple jQuery click event bind not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

This seems to work in nearly every browser except IE8 (and probably IE7, but I haven't tried that yet), and I'm not sure why.

```
$('body')
    .on('click', '.toggle', function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

I notice when I click a link classed `toggle`, the browser goes to the page top despite the `e.preventDefault()`. In looking into the problem, I've seen solutions like returning false or setting `event.returnValue = false`. I've tried both of these by first testing for `e.preventDefault()` then executing the alternative if the condition is not met.

Setting return value:

```
$('body')
    .on('click', '.toggle', function(e){
        if (e.preventDefault()) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                e.returnValue = false;
            }
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
```

I've also tried that one by setting `returnValue` on the global event object rather than the `e` passed into the bound function as was suggested in one post.

My attempt returning false:

```
$('body')
    .on('click', '.toggle', function(e){
        if (e.preventDefault()) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        return false;
    });
```

Despite all these different attempts, IE8 is taking the link's default action *and* is not toggling the class. What am I doing wrong here? I'm using jQuery 1.10.2.

**Update:** Got to the root of the issue. Thanks, everyone, for the help. I had conditionally included some script elements for non-IE, and this script was one of them. Returning false is doing the trick for me now. Thanks so much for pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: This may not solve the issue, but should be done anyway.  Remove the empty parenthesis in your if statements, so they read `if (e.preventDefault) {`

Comment: Where are you binding this event?  Even though you are using delegation, `'body'` doesn't exist until the DOM is ready.  Put that inside a `$(document).ready(` or change it to `$(document).on(`.  I changed it to `$(document).on` and it works for me in IE 8 (in a WinXP virtual machine).

Comment: @RocketHazmat - The OP said it works in every other browser, that's not the issue.

Comment: @Adam: Just a thought. :)

Comment: Not solving your concrete problem, but - use button tags for clickable elements that just execute js and have nothing to do with navigation. It's easy to style them in modern browsers and has many benefits over forcing a tags to not work like links

Comment: @JonasH Yeah, I would love to except that the client wants jQuery Mobile which wraps buttons in some additional styled markup. It was faster to use `a` elements than to try to track down and override all the styles. It's not an ideal solution, but it works well enough. Thanks!

Comment: @RocketHazmat My issue is resolved, but, for the record, I had this binding in a script included at the end of the body. I've read adding a script as the last element in the body is equivalent to wrapping with `$(document).ready()`. Is that correct?

Comment: @raddevon: Yeah, that should be the same.  At the end of the `<body>` everything should be ready to go :-)

Answer (score 3):

There's an error in your JS somewhere other than here - it's halting execution and therefore your event handler never gets bound.

Open up dev tools (F12) and refresh your page and you'll see a script error. This is what's causing the problem.

Also, remember that

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

is the same as

```
return false;
```

It's also kind of strange to stopPropagation() and an event handler that's bound to the body element anyway, although I guess it will stop the event from bubbling up to the document...

**EDIT #2**

There's one of 3 things going on - 1) there's an error in your code somewhere else that halts execution and the handlers don't get bound, 2) there's an error in your code inside the event handler (there's not from what you posted) or 3) you unbind this event handler (or all event handlers on the body element) specifically in IE8 (unlikely).

Start adding some console.log's to figure out which one of the above is causing your problem.

To be perfectly clear, your event handler should look like this:

```
$('body').on('click','.toggle',function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I reloaded with IE8 devtools open, but I don't see any error. My console is clean after the page loads. I also tried a reload in Chrome devtools. Besides complaining that it can't find source maps for my minified files, I'm not getting errors there either.

Answer (score 2):

In IE8 `event` object doesn't have `preventDefault` method. Calling it in your code shall give you such error in console:

```
TypeError: Object #<MouseEvent> has no method 'preventDefault'
```

This error causes the script to **stop immediately** so the anchor can do its primary job which is follow the href. Instead of that use:

```
$('body').on('click', '.toggle', function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The "event" passed to the function is a [jQuery event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).  jQuery adds a [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method.  It "normalizes" the object, so that it acts the same across *all* browsers.

Comment: I've changed my code to reflect exactly what you have here. The page still scrolls to the top, and my classes are still not toggled.